# How do you apply an action to only one layer?

Tags: layers, texture, actions

I have Adobe Photoshop 2020 and I am trying to apply an action to a hair texture. The problem is, I only want the action applied to one of the layers and not all of them. When I complete the action, the layers are merged and the action is placed over them all. Is there a way to apply an action to only one layer?

I have already tried making the layers clipping masks, locking the layers I don't want to change, and removing the background. Removing the background would work, however, I do not have the refine hair tool with 2020.

Comment: This is not really about actions themselves but how this one particular action has been made. This theres no generic answer.

Comment: Actions generally apply to the selected layer, unless there's something in the action that would merge layers or apply it to all layers. So it's hard to say what the problem is without access to your image file, and the action itself.

Answer (score 1):

Merge must be one line of the action.

Use the reveal arrow to show the steps, then disable the appropriate line…

[image]